How to disable/remove the new AI search features?
It appears one of the two issues has been (temporarily?) resolved:

display of nonsensical responses to general string searches [removed/disabled]
autoconversion of random strings into tags [still occurring]

------------------- original post
Within the last few hours someone thought it was a good idea to let loose the new AI search experiment on general text searches.
I run a general search on the string 'ksh' to get a list of recent Q&A's and I'm presented with this little tidbit that tells me how to create a directory:

I'm receiving similar nonsensical responses to other general string searches, eg 'sybase', and 'shell scripting'.
The good news is this feature doesn't seem to apply to searches on tags, eg, '[bash]' results in the normal Q&A list (no AI experimental answer).
The bad news is this new AI experiment also autoconverts some search strings to tags, eg, 'oracle' autoconverts to '[oracle]', 'database' is autoconverted to `[database]', 'bash' is autoconverted to '[bash]'.  Searching for 'oracle' is not the same as searching for '[oracle]' but now I don't have this option.
So, how do I disable these new 'features':

display of nonsensical responses to general string searches
autoconversion of strings into tags


See The new AI search feature's "Save as Q&A" button is in blatant violation of the community's ban on generative AI

The "feature" seems to be gone at the moment.

@yivi I read through that post (AI/Save as Q&A) before coming here; I'm not interested in, nor commenting on, the 'Save as Q&A' button (regardless of what that's supposed to do); I'm interested in getting rid of this unwanted, useless AI tweak to the UI

Since the feature you mention is not currently enabled, and apparently it was only briefly enabled (by mistake?) we do not know what final form it might have, and it posting support questions about said feature might be premature.

see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403304/was-the-new-ai-search-feature-test-officially-announced

see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403291/how-to-opt-out-of-ai-search

I answered this on this other MSO post but essentially it was an accident that it was turned on :)

As suddenly and mysteriously as it appeared, AI search vanished.
Tag conversion, on the other hand, is something that's been around since almost the dawn of the site so of course it's still around. It affects the top 60 tags on every site, unless those keywords are put in "quotes".

Relevant (but unanswered at the time of writing): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/403304/332043

Releasing this feature in the first place was apparently an accident. It's been turned back off. From the official post:

To be clear, there are no current plans to release this on the public platform, even in the future. We've turned it back off.

So it seems like this won't be coming back anytime soon.
